# How to sequentially compare the types in two tuples?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like to sequentially compare the types in two tuples and return a tuple containing 0's and 1's to represent matching and non matching types.

1. The two tuples do not have to be of equal length
2. The length of the outputted tuple will always match the length of `T1`
3. The types are compared for an exact match

**Code**

```
type Equals<X, Y> = [X] extends [Y] ? [Y] extends [X] ? true : false : false;

type TupleElementComparison<T1 extends readonly unknown[], T2 extends readonly unknown[]> =
    {[K in keyof T1]: Equals<T1[K], T2[K]> extends true ?  1 : 0}
```

**Example usage**

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAogjgVwIYBsDOAeAGgGigTQD4oBeKAbSwF0oIAPYCAOwBM0L8aB%20Dm%20x1u0rcowAE4JoALigAzVGmlyFEANwBYAFBbQkKABUEYFBBgmAts2ABhAPbmwSMQEs0tphn0BGWg2ZsoMQgkFncUECgEJgBrJlsAdyZyKjx9ACZfAQCgkLCIqNiEpKpiEi0oCqgAb3IAaShnJihoiBBbWQMvKhl4ZHRPLzqUgzSh4n5-dnFJKB4oHxkABgBfLTXNXWh6JAcTHzJDY1MLKzsHJ1d3DHI0cUaAczwmBHMAIwgxYZu7pkeoZ7eHxKWgA9CCKF48F11ptfDsjhkDkYTGYIJYmDZ7I4XG4PN8XL8ni93p88PiHkTAWI8AAxKIAY2AzncwM0YIhUKoMPAWzo8JMABZSAZkcc0acsRdcddbgS-gCSXhXrZbCYkExKYqoHSmIzmRqoLKHl8FR8lSq1QajYTDT8-jq9e5NUDCKDweRFnhPVBvd7IT6udoNjy4bsIABmYWHFEnDFnbGXPHW%20XEs1QZWq4IG03U7UMplO21yr7J525jOWsus9nkf11qFer1UIA)

```
type example1 = TupleElementComparison<[string, number], [string, number]>
// [1, 1]

type example2 = TupleElementComparison<[string, number], [string, number, Function]>
// [1, 1]

type example4 = TupleElementComparison<[string, number, boolean, number, Function, string], [number, boolean, string, string, Function, number]>
// [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

type example3 = TupleElementComparison<[string, number, boolean, number, Function, string], [string, number, boolean, number]>
// [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

**Question**

`TupleElementComparison` actually outputs the expected result - when you mouseover the resultant type in the playground - but i'm getting the following error when accessing `T2` with `K` that i'm unable to fix

`Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'T2'.`

Is there a way to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You need to assure TS that `K` represents `keyof T2`.

```js
type TupleElementComparison<T1 extends readonly unknown[], T2 extends readonly unknown[]> =
    {[K in keyof T1]:  Equals<T1[K], T2[K & keyof T2]> extends true ?  1 : 0}
```